# How can I save the coordinates of a Matrix Maze resolution?

Tags: c#, path, breadth-first-search, maze

Let's say I have a maze in a bidimensional array where I can only step on fields filled with 1, for example:

> 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
> 0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
> 0 1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
> 0 1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
> 0 1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
> 0 1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
> 0 0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
> 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

Assuming that I'll always have an start point and an end point, I need to save which coordinates I'm stepping to reach the goal. For example, if my start point is (0, 0) and my end point is (2,9), the output should be a List with the coordinates

`(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9),(0,10),(1,10),(2,10),(2,9)`

I've tried implementing a kind of A* algorithm but for this kind of problem I think it's over complicated (or maybe I'm just not understanding it). Also I implemented a simple BFS to check the minimum path. I don't really know if it is useful for a backtracking.

```
public static class BFS
    {
        public static int ROW = 20;
        public static int COL = 9;

        public class Point
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;

            public Point(int x, int y)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
        };

        public class queueNode
        {
            public Point pt;
            public int dist;

            public queueNode(Point pt, int dist)
            {
                this.pt = pt;
                this.dist = dist;
            }
        };

        static bool isValid(int row, int col)
        {
            return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) &&
                   (col >= 0) && (col < COL);
        }

        static int[] rowNum = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
        static int[] colNum = { 0, -1, 1, 0 };

        static int AplicarBFS(int[,] mat, Point src,
                                   Point dest)
        {
            if (mat[src.x, src.y] != 1 ||
                mat[dest.x, dest.y] != 1)
                return -1;

            bool[,] visited = new bool[ROW, COL];

            visited[src.x, src.y] = true;

            Queue<queueNode> q = new Queue<queueNode>();

            queueNode s = new queueNode(src, 0);
            q.Enqueue(s); 

            while (q.Count != 0)
            {
                queueNode curr = q.Peek();
                Point pt = curr.pt;

                if (pt.x == dest.x && pt.y == dest.y)
                {

                    return curr.dist;
                }

                q.Dequeue();

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    int row = pt.x + rowNum[i];
                    int col = pt.y + colNum[i];

                    if (isValid(row, col) &&
                            mat[row, col] == 1 &&
                       !visited[row, col])
                    {
                        visited[row, col] = true;
                        queueNode Adjcell = new queueNode
                                   (new Point(row, col),
                                        curr.dist + 1);
                        q.Enqueue(Adjcell);
                    }
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }

        public static int EncontrarCaminoMinimo(int[,] Matriz, int xOrigen, int yOrigen, int xDestino, int yDestino)
        {
            Point source = new Point(xOrigen, yOrigen);
            Point dest = new Point(xDestino, yDestino);

            int dist = AplicarBFS(Matriz, source, dest);

            if (dist != -1)
                Console.WriteLine("Shortest Path is " + dist);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Shortest Path doesn't exist");

            return dist;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I'm working with this:

```
public class matrixNode
        {
            public int fr = 0, to = 0, sum = 0;
            public int x, y;
            public matrixNode parent;
        }

        public static matrixNode EncontrarAStar(int[,] matrix, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
        {
            Dictionary<string, matrixNode> greens = new Dictionary<string, matrixNode>(); //open 
            Dictionary<string, matrixNode> reds = new Dictionary<string, matrixNode>(); //closed 

            matrixNode startNode = new matrixNode { x = fromX, y = fromY };
            string key = startNode.x.ToString() + startNode.x.ToString();
            greens.Add(key, startNode);

            Func<KeyValuePair<string, matrixNode>> smallestGreen = () =>
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, matrixNode> smallest = greens.ElementAt(0);

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, matrixNode> item in greens)
                {
                    if (item.Value.sum < smallest.Value.sum)
                        smallest = item;
                    else if (item.Value.sum == smallest.Value.sum
                            && item.Value.to < smallest.Value.to)
                        smallest = item;
                }

                return smallest;
            };

            List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> fourNeighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>()
                                               { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(-1,0),
                                                 new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0,1),
                                                 new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 0),
                                                 new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0,-1) };

            int maxX = matrix.GetLength(0);
            if (maxX == 0)
                return null;
            int maxY = matrix.GetLength(1);

            while (true)
            {
                if (greens.Count == 0)
                    return null;

                KeyValuePair<string, matrixNode> current = smallestGreen();
                if (current.Value.x == toX && current.Value.y == toY)
                    return current.Value;

                greens.Remove(current.Key);
                reds.Add(current.Key, current.Value);

                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> plusXY in fourNeighbors)
                {
                    int nbrX = current.Value.x + plusXY.Key;
                    int nbrY = current.Value.y + plusXY.Value;
                    string nbrKey = nbrX.ToString() + nbrY.ToString();
                    if (nbrX < 0 || nbrY < 0 || nbrX >= maxX || nbrY >= maxY
                        || matrix[nbrX, nbrY] == 0 //Obstacles marcats amb 0
                        || reds.ContainsKey(nbrKey))
                        continue;

                    if (greens.ContainsKey(nbrKey))
                    {
                        matrixNode curNbr = greens[nbrKey];
                        int from = Math.Abs(nbrX - fromX) + Math.Abs(nbrY - fromY);
                        if (from < curNbr.fr)
                        {
                            curNbr.fr = from;
                            curNbr.sum = curNbr.fr + curNbr.to;
                            curNbr.parent = current.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        matrixNode curNbr = new matrixNode { x = nbrX, y = nbrY };
                        curNbr.fr = Math.Abs(nbrX - fromX) + Math.Abs(nbrY - fromY);
                        curNbr.to = Math.Abs(nbrX - toX) + Math.Abs(nbrY - toY);
                        curNbr.sum = curNbr.fr + curNbr.to;
                        curNbr.parent = current.Value;
                        greens.Add(nbrKey, curNbr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But, for example from (2, 0) to (5, 17) happens something similar to:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt9G1.png)

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I've solved it, in a few days I'm posting the code and a fiddle!

Comment: Save your path in a `List<Point>`, `Point[]` or whatever collection of `Point`

Comment: Solving it with Dijkstra (and with A* too) will provide you that list

Comment: @Cid Thanks for your answer, but I can't figure out how to do it. Do I need an adjacency matrix of the "maze" and work it as a graph? I have no idea where to start it.

Comment: You are on the good track with your `int[,] Matriz`. Keep going, you'll solve it

Comment: @Cid I feel really lost at this point. I think I'm mixing concepts and I need to refocus. Thank you anyway, I'll keep trying!

Comment: Could you check my edit and see what is going wrong? TY!